# Any way to enable full styling of :visited links in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

I want to enable opacity change of visited links for personal use in my local browser only, for a userscript. Is there any hidden setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. See [styling restrictions for `:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited):

> For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit which styles you can
>   apply using this pseudo-class, and how they can be used:
>
> - Allowable CSS properties are `color`, `background-color`, `border-color`, `border-bottom-color`, `border-left-color`,
>     `border-right-color`, `border-top-color`, `column-rule-color`, and
>     `outline-color`.
> - Allowable SVG attributes are `fill` and `stroke`.
> - The alpha component of the allowed styles will be ignored. The alpha component of the element's non-`:visited` state will be used
>     instead, except when that component is 0, in which case the style set
>     in `:visited` will be ignored entirely.
> - Although these styles can be change the appearance of colors to the end user, the `window.getComputedStyle` method will lie and always
>     return the value of the non-`:visited` color.

Also see [Privacy and the `:visited` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I asked if there was any hidden setting to change it, in about:config or something else.

Comment: @DD3R Not that I know of. There [used to be a setting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Layout.css.visited_links_enabled) but it seems to have been removed. And even if you wanted to only enable this because of the userscript, you would actually enable it on every site. I don't see a usecase where that is desirable and I highly doubt that there is a setting to change that on a URL-level.

Comment: Yeah it would be enabled everywhere, but it would be on just one profile where I don't care about privacy that much.